# Constraints on interface members in typescript generics

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, constraints

I have a method, that should accepts any object, as long as all its fields are strings or numbers

I made this, which works great with duck typing

```
static interpolateParams(
    route: string, 
    params: {[key: string] : string | number}) : string {

    const parts = route
        .split("/")
        .map(part => {
            const match = part.match(/:([a-zA-Z09]*)\??/);
            if (match) {
                if (!params[match[1]]) {
                    console.error("route argument was not provided", route, match[1]);
                    return part;
                }

                return params[match[1]];
            }
            else {
                return part;
            }
        })

    return "/" + parts.slice(1).join("/");
}
```

and call

```
interpolateParams("/api/:method/:value", {method: "abc", value: 10});
```

Now I want to make `interpolateParams` to accept any interface for route `params`.

```
interpolateParams<IABCParams>("/api/:method/:value", {method: "abc", value: 10});
```

**Problem is that it still should match constraints for all fields being strings or numbers**

Is there a way to specify generic constraint on all fields of given interface to be of certain type?

I tried that

```
static interpolateParams<T extends {[key: string] : string | number}>(
    route: string, 
    params: T) : string {
```

and obviously got this

> Type 'IABCParams' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string | number; }'.
>
> Index signature is missing in type 'IABCParams'.

Thanks

Comment: My guess: no, there isn't. Would love to be wrong.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd that sems to be possible, check Matt's comment and my final version, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`T`'s constraint can refer to `T` (with some restrictions), so you can use a mapped type to generate a constraint that has the same fields as `T`:

```
function interpolateParams<T extends {[P in keyof T] : string | number}>(
    route: string, 
    params: T) : string { /*...*/ }
```

Beware that trickery with circular type parameter constraints can sometimes cause problems, though this scenario will likely be OK.

Comment: Ok, that did not work quite well, but with additional layer it seems to tricked interpreter :) As you described, error in `if (!params[match[1]]) ` line - no indexer. So I added another version of interpolateRoute as you suggested, and inside call bare interpolate (see next for code)

Answer (score 2):

Here is final version, thanks Matt for hint

```
static interpolateParams(
    route: string, 
    params: {[key: string] : string | number}) : string {

    const parts = route
        .split("/")
        .map(part => {
            const match = part.match(/:([a-zA-Z09]*)\??/);
            if (match) {
                if (!params[match[1]]) {
                    if (part.endsWith("?")) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    console.error("route argument was not provided", route, match[1]);
                    return part;
                }

                return params[match[1]];
            }
            else {
                return part;
            }
        }).filter(p => p && p != "");

    return "/" + parts.join("/");
}

static formatRoute<T extends {[P in keyof T] : string | number}>(
    route: string,
    params: T
) : string {
    return interpolateParams(route, params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `interpolateParams("/api/:method/:value", {method: "abc", value: 10});` to typecheck you can't. This is because you cannot infer anything about `"/api/:method/:value"` to give you a `method,value` signature.

## Workaround

Write functions that take `method` and `value` and use it to power *both* the config and the use.

E.g. this is the strategy I use with [takeme](http://basarat.com/takeme/#/?id=managing-links).

```
// Define 
export const links = {
  profile: (id: string) => `/profile/${id}`
}

// Use in Configure 
links.profile(':profileId')

// Use in Navigate / a tags
links.profile(user.id)
```