# Why generic's constraint for properties fails with interface but not with type

Tags: typescript

Look at this snippet:

```
type Constrained<T extends { [K in string]: string }> = T;

type A = {
    p: string;
}

interface B {
    p: string;
}

type R1 = Constrained<A>; // Why this is OK...
type R2 = Constrained<B>; // ... and this an Error?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Constrained%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20T%3B%0A%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20p%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20p%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20R1%20%3D%20Constrained%3CA%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20Why%20this%20is%20OK...%0Atype%20R2%20%3D%20Constrained%3CB%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20...%20and%20this%20an%20Error%3F%0A)

I know the constraint could be expressed differently to avoid the error, for instance,

```
type Constrained<T extends { [K in keyof T]: string }> = T;
```

and solutions like this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52731753/2484624) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483282/2484624).

The main question is: **why the `interface` fails but the `type` does not?**

My guess is because `interface`s are open-ended (they can be extended/merged).

Since the error message is something like

> Index signature is missing in type 'B'.

I think [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029) is relevant. In that case another question arises:

**Is a type declared with `type` the representation of an object literal type?**

Comment: "object literal type" --- object literal is a way to represent JS object in code, it's not a special type.